# Can't add large number of rules to iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, limit

I made a very simple bash script (echo at start, runs commands, echos at end) to add approx 7300 rules to iptables blocking much of China and Russia, however it gets through adding approximately 400 rules before giving the following error for every subsequent attempt to add a rule to that chain:

```
iptables: Unknown error 18446744073709551615
```

I even tried manually adding rules afterwards and it won't let me add them (it gives the same error).

The command to add each rule looks like this:

```
/sbin/iptables -A sshguard -s x.x.x.0/x -j DROP
```

`sshguard` is a chain I created for use with the [sshguard](http://www.sshguard.net/) daemon, and I wanted to add the rules there so I wasn't muddying up the `INPUT` chain. The ip ranges I am supplying are not to blame here, as I have supplied valid ranges to test and they are met with the same error. Flushing the chain of rules and adding individual ones work, but again, not after ~400 entries.

I did some googling beforehand, but the others having this issue don't seem to be having it for the same reasons I am.

Is there some kind of rule limit per chain with iptables? Also, is this the proper way to go about blocking these ranges (errors aside)?

```
# iptables -V
iptables v1.3.5

# cat /etc/issue
CentOS release 5.8 (Final)

# uname -a 
Linux domain.com 2.6.18-028stab101.1 #1 SMP Sun Jun 24 19:50:48 MSD 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Edit:** To clarify, the bash script is running each iptables command individually, not looping through a file or list of IPs.

Also, my purpose for blocking these ranges is preventative -- I am trying to limit the amount of bots that scrape, crawl, or attempt to create spam accounts on a few of my websites. I am already using [sshguard](http://www.sshguard.net/) to block brute force attempts on my server, but that does not help with the other bots, obviously.

Comment: Learn about the `NFQUEUE` target and use `nfblock.`  Much more elegant.

Comment: Does that work on CentOS 5.x without recompiling the kernel?

Comment: if your kernel has `NFQUEUE` target support built-in or available as a module then no kernel recompile needed.  You'll need to compile `nfblock` though unless you find an `.rpm` for it.  NFQUEUE was introduced with 2.6.14.

Comment: This is what [IP Sets](http://ipset.netfilter.org/) are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.

I should have mentioned that I had a Virtuozzo container for my VPS. http://kb.parallels.com/en/746 mentions the following:

> Also it might be required to increase numiptent barrier value to be
>   able to add more iptables rules:
>
> `~# vzctl set 101 --save --numiptent 400`

FYI: The container has to be restarted for this to take effect.

This explains why I hit the limit at around 400. If I had CentOS 6, I would install the `ipset` module (EPEL) for `iptables` instead of adding all these rules (because `ipset` is fast).

As it stands now, on CentOS 5.9, I'd have to compile `iptables` > `1.4.4` and my kernel to get `ipset`. Since this is a VPS and my host may eventually upgrade to CentOS 6, I am not going to pursue that.

Answer (score 1):

It's not hard to debug, but if you convert the rules to pure iptables commands, and execute them one by one (use a shell script), you'd see the errors, normally would be missing of some ipt modules.

First use `iptables-save` to export current rules, then do something like this to debug that line-by-line:

`egrep '^(-A|-I)' ok.rules | while read x; do iptables $x || { echo failed $x; break; }; done`

I googled a bit, it seems to be a bug on CentOS's default kernel config.

Comment: That's what I did. Like I said, it was a very simple bash script; I had ~7300 lines that looked just like the example I gave. All the iptables commands after ~400 give the same "unknown error". I ran `service iptables save` before executing the script, so it was simple to revert using `service iptables restart`. If it's a bug in CentOS' kernel config, I'm not sure there's much I can do about that given that it's a virtual dedicated server (can't do kernel modifications, afaik).

Answer (score 1):

There looks to be an open bug in RHEL regarding iptables.. You might be hitting it.
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=598380

In the mean time, have you looked at something like `denyhosts` ? It will automatically add entries to `hosts.deny` as you are attacked (ssh attacks)

Just a thought.

Comment: I use sshguard (www.sshguard.net) to block attacks dynamically. I looked into `fail2ban` and `denyhosts`, but those would be redundant with sshguard running. That said, the main issue is that I want to block these IP ranges preemptively, because of crawlers and scrapers in those regions.